# What is the difference between 応える and 応じる?

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between 応える and 応じる? I know they both mean 'answer' but is there an actual difference?

> このタイ料理の店は客の好みに応えて味や量を調節してくれる。

can I use both or just one　(why?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic meaning of 応じる is just responding. ～に応じて is typically translated as "according to ～" or "in response to ～". The response can sometimes be an unfavorable one. On the other hand, 応える has a connotation of proactively meeting someone's expectation. [期待に応える](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=meet%20expectation) is a common set phrase. In your example, 客の好みに応えて and 客の好みに応じて are interchangeable, but the former might sound slightly more "active".

To take another example, 要求に応じる tends to be used when giving in to an unreasonable request, while 要求に応える tends to be used when trying to please someone actively.